# Replace '\n' with newlines in logs of sh() command in Groovy Jenkins script

Tags: jenkins, logging, replace, newline, eol

I have some deployment jenkinsfile script, where I am executing some npm command:

```
sh 'npm run deploy'
```

This script returns some long logs with '\n' signs, that are not converted into new lines, eg:

```
2022-01-01T15:28:04.76+0000 [STG/0] OUT -----> Download go 1.15.5\n   2022-01-01T15:28:12.05+0000 [STG/0] OUT -----> Running go build supply\n   2022-01-01T15:28:12.05+0000 [STG/0] OUT /tmp/buildpackdownloads/a7e0be7204d320dabd24f8a94bc4cdc8 ~\n   2022-01-01T15:28:13.16+0000 [STG/0] OUT ~\n   2022-01-01T15:28:13.17+0000 [STG/0] OUT -----> Nodejs Buildpack version 1.7.65\n   2022-01-01T15:28:13.28+0000 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing binaries\n   2022-01-01T15:28:13.28+0000 [STG/0] OUT        engines.node (package.json): ^14.15 || ^16.13\n   2022-01-01T15:28:13.28+0000 [STG/0] OUT        engines.npm (package.json): unspecified (use default)\n   2022-01-01T15:28:13.28+0000 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing node 16.13.1\n   2022-01-01T15:28:13.28+0000 [STG/0] OUT        Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/node/node_16.13.1_linux_x64_cflinuxfs3_7f893010.tgz]\n   2022-01-01T15:28:15.34+0000 [STG/0] OUT        Using default npm version: 8.1.2\n   2022-01-01T15:28:15.34+0000 [STG/0] OUT -----> Installing yarn 1.22.17
```

How can I convert those '\n' from sh() output into new lines? How can I break those lines? I was googled for a solution without any success... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `log` variable to a `list` using `split`. Then you could iterate through the list using a for loop:

```
lines = log.split('\n')
lines.each { line -> println line }//print all lines of log variable
```